# how to make good css layouts

Tags: css

I currently know a bit CSS and also HTML, i also made a few websites. But the designs of my websites are always crappy and the code is also. I really want to make very beautiful websites. Does anyone got good starting points?

Like is this website a good point to start:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/10-hand-picked-tutorials-for-beginning-web-designers/

Comment: I think that's something you can better judge yourself. We do not know your skill sets.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you first read some epic posts here:

- [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet
- [Common Web UI Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131384/common-web-ui-styles)
- [Should I teach CSS layout directly to new learners or should I first teach how to make layout with tables, then table-less layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147217/should-i-teach-css-layout-directly-to-new-learners-or-should-i-first-teach-how-to)
- [Fluid layouts with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828926/fluid-layouts-with-css)
- [How to make css smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985627/how-to-make-css-smaller)

Also, always have in mind some important things:

- HTML must be semantic. Create your
  HTML structure like it meaning not it
  appearance.
- Use CSS to all positioning. Remember
  that `float`, `position`, `z-index`
  and `clear` are your friends.
- Avoid specific browser hacks. In
  fact, almost all can be done exactly
  for IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and
  Safari. Near we have IE8 (only
  without CSS3 things). Your hard way
  will be IE7, but it isn't so much
  away from IE8.
- Choose your browsers by audience and
  graphics [like
  this](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201005-201105).
  I don't care about IE6 anymore and
  I'm stoping to care about IE7 too.
- Using `table` isn't a crime. Tables
  was created to tabular data, i.e.
  grids, lists with more than 2
  columns, etc.
- Using `table` is a crime. Don't use
  it for your layout structure, like
  menus, headers, footers, etc.
- Using `div` also can be a crime.
  "Tableless" doesn't means "Divmore".
  Your markup must be clean and
  semantic ever. Dozens of divs are so
  bad as tables could be.
- Read [W3C
  Specs](http://dev.w3.org/cvsweb/) and
  understand the web standards like you
  understand your own name.

And always discuss (here with us or on many blogs about it) why some approach is better than other.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Nice links and also incredible hints.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good resources out there.  Here are a list of a few that I have used in the past:

http://www.smashingapps.com/2011/03/29/40-excellent-yet-free-css-tools-and-generators-for-developers.html

http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/

http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/04/19/10-excellent-free-web-apps-to-create-css-forms-and-grids.html

http://www.smashingapps.com/2010/07/27/top-17-websites-to-easily-generate-css-grid-layouts.html

Comment: I don't wanna use grid yet because i am not so familiar with CSS, I think using grids like after a year of experience.